# How to access attributes from launchSettings.json file in Razor Pages (Blazor WebAssembly)?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor, blazor-webassembly

```
        "APIs": {
        "API-1": "http://localhost:5000/student",
        "API-2":  "http://localhost:5001/teacher"}
```

I created these attributes in launchSettings.json file. Now I need to access API-1 and API-2 values in Student.razor page.
I tried to use it like this..

```
List<Student> students = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Student>>("API-1");
```

Comment: launchSettings.json is used for development only. There isn't launchSettings in prod

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't use launchsettings for that, you should use appsettings.json

Create an appsettings.json in wwwroot and put your api config in there.

```
{
  "APIs": {
    "API-1": "http://localhost:5000/student",
    "API-2": "http://localhost:5001/teacher"
  }
}
```

Then `inject` `IConfiguration` wherever you need it.
e.g.

```
@inject Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration config
```

and

```
List<Student> students = await http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Student>>(config["APIs:API-1"]);
```

Comment: @Shruti, this is the correct answer...why don't you accept it !?